# Bash script Multiply only numbers from a text file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am looking for a bash command that will multiply only numbers from a text file. Below is the content of my text file. I need multiply all numbers by 100.

```
    0 4530000 sil
4530000 11100000 ow
11100000 6320000 p
6320000 7600000 ah
7600000 8410000 n
8410000 12100000 sil
```

For single line with only number,I am using something like this below

```
for file in *.txt; \
do y=`sed -n '1 p' "$file"`;
   z=$(bc<<<"$y*100")
   sed $file -i -e 's/'"$y"'/'"$z"'/'
done
```

But I dont know how to do it for multiple lines, with alphabets in them. Number of lines in my file are not fixed, each file has different number of lines with max being 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can use perl

```
perl -pe 's/\b(\d+\.)?\d+\b/$&*100/ge' file
```

Comment: Yes. I can use perl although I'm not familiar. Can you write full code with 'for loop', that works for each text file? Also do explain each character.

Comment: That's it, put that in your loop and remove everything else. Add -i to the flags if you want inplace replacement.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could also explain what the slashes along with alphabets mean.

Comment: @abhinandanbr do you know how sed replacement works?

Comment: Actually I am not aware of it.

Comment: @abhinandanbr You used it in your question? There is plenty of documentation. See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html

Comment: Thanks. One last thing. What if I have decimal number like 0.0001? For that it fails.

Comment: @abhinandanbr updated answer.

Comment: Nice answer for numbers formatted as ints (e.g 1500) or floats (e.g. 1.5), but it won't work for scientific notation (e.g. 1.5e3)

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying all numbers by 100, for integers, means adding 00 to the end of each number if >0.

```
sed 's/[1-9][0-9]*/&00/g' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU or `busybox` `awk`, recognising numbers like `1.2`, `.123e-4`:

```
awk -v CONVFMT=%.19g \
    -v RS='\\<[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?\\>' \
    -v ORS= 'RT != "" {RT *= 100}; {print $0 RT}'
```

You may want to adapt `CONVFMT` for the format of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk. Save this as parse.awk:

```
{
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
    number = match($i, /[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?/)
    printf number? "%g " : "%s ", number? $i * 100 : $i
  }
  printf "\n"
}
```

And then run:

```
awk -f parse.awk file
```

Or if you want a one-liner:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){n=match($i,/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?/);printf n?"%g ":"%s ",n?$i*100:$i} printf"\n"}' file
```