# dividing all numbers in a file using shell scripting

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have file with 27 columns and 45000 rows

```
head test_1

    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
    16  20  24  20  20  10  6   28  36  10  26  14  24  24  24  30  24  30  24  
    2   8   2   4   2   0   0   10  8   2   6   0   6   4   4   6   2   10  2   
    14  12  22  16  18  10  6   20  28  8   20  14  18  20  20  24  22  20  22  
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   
    16  20  24  20  20  10  6   30  36  10  26  14  24  24  24  28  22  30  24  
    0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I want to divide each value by some constant number (here 2) using shell  scripting. How can I do it?
I tried something like `awk -v c=2 '{ print $0/c }' test_1` , but it prints only the first column!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash script Multiply only numbers from a text file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400589/bash-script-multiply-only-numbers-from-a-text-file)

Comment: I propose to leave this question open as the duplicate mention provide only very ugly oneliners without precise explanation of the effect.

Comment: @Kiwy The better reason to leave it open is that the asker wants to know whyt is wrong with his code. The other question does not answer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `awk -v c=2 '{ print $0/c }' test_1` would only print the first column as it would try to divide each complete line with `c`.  The conversion of the line into a single number throws away everything that is not a number, i.e. the first whitespace and everything after it.

Instead, you need to loop over the columns:

```
awk -v c=2 '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) $i /= c; print }' OFS='\t' test_1
```

This code simply sets the value of each column to itself divided by `c`, and then prints the line with the modified values. `NF` is the number of fields (columns) on the current line, and `$i` will be the value in column `i`. The `OFS='\t'` at the end sets the output field separator to a tab character.

The result for the given data will be

```
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
8       10      12      10      10      5       3       14      18      5       13      7       12      12      12      15      12      15      12
1       4       1       2       1       0       0       5       4       1       3       0       3       2       2       3       1       5       1
7       6       11      8       9       5       3       10      14      4       10      7       9       10      10      12      11      10      11
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0
8       10      12      10      10      5       3       15      18      5       13      7       12      12      12      14      11      15      12
0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Awfully close, but you need to divide each column individually:

```
awk -v denominator=2 '{ for( i=0;i<=NF;i++ ) { printf "%f%s",  $i/denominator, OFS }; printf "%s", ORS  }' /path/to/file
```